# React JS styled-components importing images from public folder

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, styling

I have been trying to set the image to background-image from the public folder in styled-components.
I tried so

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import Background from 'process.env.PUBLIC_URL + /images/background.svg'

export const HomeContainer = styled.section`
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  background-image: url(${Background});
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
`;
```

and so

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export const HomeContainer = styled.section`
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  background-image: url('process.env.PUBLIC_URL + /images/background.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
`;
```

How can I import it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's working for me.

```
import bgImage from "../images/background.png";

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  background-image: url(${bgImage});
`
```

Comment: it didnt work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've googled it but still have nothing just like you.

So I decided to use props:

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const HomeContainer = styled.section`
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  background-image: url(${ ({Background}) => Background });
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
`;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <HomeContainer Background={ process.env.PUBLIC_URL + 'where your image at' } />
  )
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to have jsconfig file configured with base path

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "jsx": "react",
      "baseUrl": "./",
  }
}
```

And then access your image by simply `import img from "public/images/whatever.png`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code snippet:

`background-image: url(${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/background.svg);`